# Keyboard stopped working in grub 2.02 on dual booted pc

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, keyboard

I have a dual booted PC with windows 7 and ubuntu 18.04(bionic), and the keyboard refuses to work on the grub OS selection menu thus rendering me unable to switch to booting windows. The keyboard worked fine a few times after installing Ubuntu but suddenly stopped responding after a random reboot/boot just in Grub menu(for instance can't toggle even numlock while in grub).

1. The keyboard works perfectly fine in Bios and once past the grub menu too(am even able to abort boot by hitting ctrl+alt+del before the splash
   screen).
2. I have USB legacy support enabled.
3. Have tried turning on fast boot in bios with partial as well as full USB support on. Have tried with fast boot turned off.
4. Have tried a PS2 keyboard too, doesn't work either.
5. Have tried plugging keyboard into all the USB ports on the PC USB2.0 as well as 3.0
6. Tried adding a flag to the grub file that makes sure that it won't
   proceed without keyboard input: just in case the keyboard would turn
   on after a delay. This led me to having to fix grub from a live USB
   as the keyboard still refused to work and thus couldn't boot anymore
   without keyboard input.
7. Tried with XCHI Hand-off and EHCI hand-off turned ON/OFF.
8. Tried reseting bios by reinserting CMOS as well as reloading an older working profile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this device is my daily driver and I can't do a lot of things without booting windows. Thank you.

Comment: My Asus motherboard has Legacy UEFI Enabled, Intel xHCI mode set to Smart Auto and EHCI mode set to Disabled. Grub typically relies on BIOS as Ubuntu has not loaded its keyboard driver until booted.

Comment: So I've heard, but I think I mentioned pretty much all the settings I could alter in BIOS? if not can you please suggest something  I missed out trying?

Comment: Have you tried using another version of grub ?

Comment: Have you updated BIOS to latest available. You probably have to redo settings after update.

Comment: 1.Bios flashed to a fairly recent version(keyboard worked with grub too as mentioned for a few days till it stopped suddenly and sometimes even works now randomly I realise.)
2.) No I haven't tried a different version of grub. Is it safe to use something else/some other version? Could you point me towards one you recommend?